# can't bypass image to another activity, i already use the intent concept, but still not works

Tags: kotlin

i already using the intent concept but still not working, and also somtimes the image is error and not showing the preview like it was
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EOkv.png)

Code :
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity()

```
//Menampilkan Preview image
lateinit var button: Button
lateinit var imageView: ImageView
companion object {
    val image_request_code = 100
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


    button = findViewById(R.id.btnPhoto)
    imageView = findViewById(R.id.defaultImg)

    //Button untuk mengambil isi gallery
    button.setOnClickListener {
        pickImageGallery()
    }

    //Inputan
    val btnSubmit = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnSubmit)
    val edNim = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edNim)
    val edNama = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edNama)
    val edEmail = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edEmail)
    val edProdi = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edProdi)

    //Button Preview
    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener{
        val nim = edNim.text.toString().toInt()
        val nama = edNama.text.toString()
        val email = edEmail.text.toString()
        val prodi = edProdi.text.toString()

        //Passing Data ke SecondActivity
        Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java).also {
            it.putExtra("extra_nim", nim)
            it.putExtra("extra_nama", nama)
            it.putExtra("extra_email", email)
            it.putExtra("extra_prodi", prodi)
            startActivity(it)
        }
    }

}
```